# No guarda el valor y aparece el error Empty query

Tags: php, sql

Si hay un valor en la consulta de sql, no toma el valor de la consulta en la variable `$acd0`

```
while (true) {
 $t= "SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM accidente";

    $query2=mysqli_query($db,$t);
    while($acd=mysqli_fetch_array($query2))



$last= current($last_id);
//  $acd_1=current($acd);
 $ls=(( $last !== false) ? $last : ", &nbsp;");
//  $acd2=(( $acd_1 !== false) ? $acd_1 : ", &nbsp;");
                $valores3='("'.$acd[0].'","'.$ls.'"),';
                $valoresQ3= substr($valores3, 0, -1);


            $acd_impl=$db->query("INSERT INTO implicado_acd (id_acd, id_implicado) VALUES $valoresQ3");
            $sqlRess1=$db->query($acd_impl) or mysql_error();

    $last = next($last_id);
    //$acd_1= next($acd); 

    if($last === false) break;
          echo "string".$acd[0];             


    }   }
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60607/discussion-on-question-by-carlos-alberto-soler-velasquez-no-guarda-el-valor-y-ap).

Comment: Sería bueno que comentes cuál ha sido la solución. En cuanto a la pregunta, creo que es algo que no se puede reproducir y creo que podrías eliminarla.

Comment: no entiendo que quieres decir pero bueno los datos se guardan solo que envia una notice del tipo array conversion to string ... pero los valores se guardan :3

Comment: no perdon fue por un echo que deje por hay ese error, la verdad no importaba